# How to set dropdown menu hidden by default

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

this is my code for a dropdown, I am using tailwindCSS and pure html,

```
<li class="relative" x-data="{isOpen:false}">
              <button  @click="isOpen=!isOpen"  class=" block text-sm font-bold outline-none  focus:outline-none  text-blue-900 " href="#">
                SERVICES</button>
              
              <div 
                class="right-0 p-2 mt-1 bg-white rounded-md shadow lg:absolute"
                :class="{'hidden':!isOpen'flex flex-col':isOpen}"
                @click.away="isOpen = false">
                <a href="#" class="flex p-2 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md  hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-black">Categories</a>

          <a href="#" class="flex p-2 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md  hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-black">Inventories</a>
                 
 <a href="#" class="flex p-2 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md  hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-black">Brands</a>
                 </div>
            </li>
```

I want to hide my dropdown by default and is should only open when someone hovers on it or when someone clicks on it. but right now it is still visible even though I have tried hiding it.
I want to be able to do it with tailwind the way I am trying to approach, I know how to do it with CSS,
Please see image for reference. and let know what am I doing wrong.[image]

Comment: refer this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: I know how to do it with CSS, but I have to use tailwind here @MAYURSANCHETI

Answer (score 1):

You have to use pure css on the drop-down container

Example
.drop-down{
display:none;
}

Comment: I am using tailwind, can you tell me how to do it using tailwind?

Comment: Also tailwind use classic css ;). But you have maybe to "override" the defaults with "display:none !important;?

Comment: @Pepe when I do that the dropdown menus disappear and doesn't get displayed on click or hover, I have also used isOpen and I am setting is false as default, can you tell why isn't that working?

Answer (score 0):

try like below, below example use tailwind CSS

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-10">

  <div class="dropdown inline-block relative">
    <button class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
      <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
      <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/> </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1">
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">One</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-b bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Three is the magic number</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this might work, but I wanted to know what is wrong with my current code

Comment: why use clickway & you not use css like above